# How to find a pair of number (A,B) whose XOR is N such that B is smallest possible

Tags: binary-operations

What I'm trying to figure out here is, if there is any way that I can find such a pair of integer such that one of it is the smallest of any number occurring in any pair of number which satisfies A XOR B = N

Comment: ... I';m not clear what you are asking.  Can you give an example?

Comment: @Bram28 thanks for asking, for example, to have 6 as XOR I have a pair (7, 1) where B is the smallest possible natural number. So is there any way I can generalize for any number?

Comment: You can always pick B=1 and A=B XOR N.

Comment: @MatthewDaly many thanks for this, just curious, what if I wish to ensure that neither A nor B can be greater than N?

Comment: Then the smallest possible value of B would correspond to the least possible 1 in the binary expansion of N.  For instance if N=12=1100 in binary, then you'd need A=8, B=4 to avoid having an A greater than N.

Answer (score 0):

You can always get your number $N$ by XOR-ing $A=N$ and $B=0$